# How to clear cache in android version 7.1

Tags: android

Please help with clearing cache in android. I am able to delete cache with below code on android version 6.0. When i am trying it in 7.1 nothing changes. what am i missing?

```
 //method to delete cache- issue reported
    public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {
            File dir = context.getCacheDir();
            deleteDir(dir);

            Log.d("cache clear", "cache delete "+dir);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            Log.d("cache clear", "cache delete 1");


            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {

            return dir.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android API 19 you can do that:

```
((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
```

Official docs:
clearApplicationUserData
added in API level 19

public boolean clearApplicationUserData ()

Permits an application to erase its own data from disk. This is equivalent to the user choosing to clear the app's data from within the device settings UI. It erases all dynamic data associated with the app -- its private data and data in its private area on external storage -- but does not remove the installed application itself, nor any OBB files. It also revokes all runtime permissions that the app has acquired, clears all notifications and removes all Uri grants related to this application.

```
Returns
boolean     true if the application successfully requested that the application's data be erased; false otherwise.
```

***EDIT***
From your Activity don't call

```
deleteCache(this)
```

but call

```
deleteCache(getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i strictly need to clear cache not app_data

Comment: Are you passing the right ApplicationContext? Or maybe are you using an externalCacheDir? In that case replace context.getCacheDir() with context.getExternalCacheDir()

Comment: From your Activity don't call deleteCache(this) call deleteCache(getApplicationContext())

Comment: thank you for replies...above code works perfectly on os 6 but not on os 7. It is getting proper context.